# Alternative to ajax request in window.beforeunload, for releasing pessimistic lock

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload, pessimistic-locking

I have a web app that handles multi-user locking - a server-side lock is set when a record is opened for editing. The lock is released either when the form is submitted, or via an ajax request in `window.beforeunload` - so it is released when the user goes back, or closes the tab, etc. (The lock times out eventually if a user never closes or submits - when it then becomes optimistic).

Chrome 80 seems to have blocked this ability to send AJAX requests in beforeunload. Is there an alternative way to do this? If not, I'm guessing I'll need to do a timed ajax ping to keep the lock - I'm just unsure if there is a best-practice for this situation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: @Teemu: this is the "official" solution. But it comes with a few cons... The most important one is that this method sends data asynchronously. In my case (which is pretty similar to the questioned one by @Matthew) the locked record is marked with a "lock icon" during the locked time. So after closing the "editor window" a request is send to check whether it is unlocked to update the icon. This MAY work with sendBeacon but it depends on the asynchronously method. Is there a better solution?

ps: another small con is that sendBeacon isn't supported by IE

Comment: @vso It has never been reliable to send an asynchronous request from `onbeforeunload`. If the response has been quick enough, this has been worked, if not, the request has been aborted when the page was unloaded. The request send by sendBeacon is guaranteed to be send to the server, and not aborted when the final page closing happens, but you can't receive the server response on the client. To release a lock, sendBacon should be an ideal solution. And yes, it's not supported by IE. In IE you can use synchronous AJAX request, it'll always be supported in IE, since it's not updated anymore.